# Attempting to retrieve common name from distinguished name when setting header

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm attempting to configure my Apache HTTPD server's httpd.conf and ssl.conf use client certificates for authentication in my web applications. The server is acting as a reverse proxy for some web applications.

I have the following rules set up for the `<Location>` tag:

```
    RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} (.+)
    RewriteRule .* - [E=RU:%1,NS]
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-User %{RU}e
```

This sets the X-Forwarded-User header to the entire distinguished name in the certificate. What I'd like to set is the common name only, which is located at the end of my DN.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an SSL variable based on the client cert that provides exactly what I needed:

```
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-User %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}e
```

RewriteCond and RewriteRule are unnecessary.

Comment: It seems in httpd 2.4 it need to be s at the end because it comes froms mod_ssl https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html %{VARNAME}s  The contents of the SSL environment variable VARNAME, if mod_ssl is enabled.